# The relationship of the integral from neg to pos infinity of f(ax+b) to that integral of f(x)

Tags: calculus

For any constants $a$ and $b$, is it always true that

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$

implies

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax+b) dx = 1/a$

Or does that only hold under certain conditions?

Comment: The $+b$ term not affecting the result of the integration follows from translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure. I am not sure about the reason for the effect from the $a$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, by the FTC, there is an antiderivative $F'(x)=f(x)$ Note that, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx=\lim_{M\to +\infty}F(M)-\lim_{m\to -\infty}F(m)
$$

Then, by direct computation, for $a\ne 0$, 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{a}F(ax+b)=f(ax+b)
$$
so that $\int_{m}^Mf(ax+b)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{a}(F(aM+b)-F(am+b))$. Then, if $a$ is positive, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax+b)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{a}\lim_{M\to +\infty}F(aM+b)-\lim_{m\to-\infty}F(am+b)\\
=\frac1a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx
$$
And if $a<0$, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax+b)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{a}\lim_{M\to +\infty}F(aM+b)-\lim_{m\to-\infty}F(am+b)\\
=-\frac1a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx
$$
So that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax+b)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response!

Answer (score 3):

It does for $a>0$. In general, for $a\ne 0$, it should rather be $\frac1{\lvert a\rvert}$.

Comment: there are assumptions on $f$ necessary to change variables

Comment: @qbert What assumptions on $f$ are necessary? I believe this is precisely what was asked in the question.

Comment: @qbert existence of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ in $\Bbb R$ absorbs any of them.

Comment: @Gae.S. Would you care to elaborate and perhaps add that to your answer?

Comment: @Gae.S.Then it's worth mentioning how. If $f$ is continuous, then this is the $u$ substitution familiar from calculus. If not, then more work is required. It's not clear to me what the question is asking for in terms of depth.

Comment: I was asking about continuous functions, I apologize for not clarifying. Thank you!

Comment: Where can I find a proof of this statement?